# One-hot encode pandas dataframe using dictionary with column name and values

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding

I currently have the below code to one-hot encode a pandas dataframe using a dictionary where keys are feature names and values are list of values for the feature.

```
def dummy_encode_dataframe(self, df, dummy_values_dict):
    for (feature, dummy_values) in sorted(dummy_values_dict.items()):
        for dummy_value in sorted(dummy_values):
            dummy_name = u'%s_%s' % (feature, dummy_value)
            df[dummy_name] = (df[feature] == dummy_value).astype(float)
        del df[feature]
    return df
```

The `dummy_values_dict` has the structure:

```
feature name (key)   list of possible values (strings)
---------            ---------------------------------
F1                   ['A', 'B', 'C', 'MISSING']
F2                   ['D', 'E', 'F', 'MISSING']
F3                   ['G', 'H', 'I']
```

with sample input/output:

```
df (one row):
====
F1     F2    F3
---  -----  -----  
'A'    'Q'   'H'
```

expected output:

```
df_output:
====
F1_A  F1_B  F1_C  F1_MISSING F2_D  F2_E  F2_F F2_MISSING F3_G  F3_H  F3_I
---   ----  -----  --------- ----  ----  ---- ---------- ----  ----  -----
 1      0     0       0        0    0     0        0       0     1    0
```

The problem is that the for-loops takes too long to run. Any way to optimize it?

**UPDATE 1:** From the comment about using OneHotEncoder in scikit-learn...
Can you elaborate on this piece of code to get the desired output?

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['F1', 'F2', 'F3']) 
df.loc[0] = ['A', 'Q', 'H'] 
dummy_values_dict = { 'F1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'MISSING'], 'F2': ['D', 'E', 'F', 'MISSING'], 'F3': ['G', 'H', 'I'] } 
# import OneHotEncoder 
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder 
categorical_cols = sorted(dummy_values_dict.keys()) 
# instantiate OneHotEncoder 
# todo: encoding...
```

Comment: Curious, reason to do this purely in pandas? Have you tried existing one-hot encoders like the one from sklearn? https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

Comment: I am doing a ML-training and storing the model together with the dummy dictionary in a database. Then there is a REST-api for prediction that receives a JSON that is trainsformed into a pandas dataframe with 1 row. This dataframe then needs to be one-hot-encoded the same way as is done during training. Therefore the dictionary of values per feature from training is used (to be able to get exact same handling of null/missing/new unseen values showing up in predict etc).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @gurkan. One of the reasons it's hard to evaluate your original approach is that we don't have access to the class definition that this belongs to or the class method `_replace_forbidden_column_name_chars`. (Who knows, maybe that's where the slowdown is?) But the additional requirements you posted in your last comment are helpful and should be part of the original post if they are critical to a solution.

Comment: OK, I removed that method in the code (not relevant at all). Problem is the looping that takes time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the question was not well phrased. I managed to find a more optimized implementation (probably there are better) using the below code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np


    def dummy_encode_dataframe_optimized(df, dummy_values_dict):

        column_headers = np.concatenate(np.array(
            [np.array([k + '_value_' + s
                       for s in sorted(dummy_values_dict[k])]) 
                       for k in sorted(dummy_values_dict.keys())]), axis=0)

        feature_values = [str(feature) + '_value_' + str(df[feature][0])
                          for feature in dummy_values_dict.keys()]

        one_hot_encode_vector = np.vectorize(lambda x: float(1) if x in feature_values else float(0))(column_headers)

        untouched_df = df.drop(df.ix[:, dummy_values_dict.keys()].head(0).columns, axis=1)

        hot_encoded_df = pd.concat(
            [
                untouched_df,
                pd.DataFrame(
                    [one_hot_encode_vector],
                    index=untouched_df.index,
                    columns=column_headers
                )
            ], axis=1
        )

        return hot_encoded_df


    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['F1', 'F2', 'F3'])
    df.loc[0] = ['A', 'Q', 'H']
    dummy_values_dict = { 'F1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'MISSING'], 'F2': ['D', 'E', 'F', 'MISSING'], 'F3': ['G', 'H', 'I'] }

    result = dummy_encode_dataframe_optimized(df, dummy_values_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

`pd.get_dummies` should work in your case, but first we need to set all the value not in the dictionary to `NaN`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'F1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'MISSING'], 'F2': [
                  'Q', 'E', 'F', 'MISSING'], 'F3': ['G', 'H', 'I', 5]})
#         F1       F2 F3
# 0        A        Q  G
# 1        B        E  H
# 2        C        F  I
# 3  MISSING  MISSING  5

dummy_values_dict = {'F1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'MISSING'], 'F2': [
    'D', 'E', 'F', 'MISSING'], 'F3': ['G', 'H', 'I']}
```

We can set all the other value to `np.nan`:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df.loc[~df[col].isin(dummy_values_dict[col]), col] = np.nan
print(df)
#         F1       F2   F3
# 0        A      NaN    G
# 1        B        E    H
# 2        C        F    I
# 3  MISSING  MISSING  NaN
```

Then we can use `pd.get_dummies` to do the job:

```
print(pd.get_dummies(df))
#    F1_A  F1_B  F1_C  F1_MISSING  F2_E  F2_F  F2_MISSING  F3_G  F3_H  F3_I
# 0     1     0     0           0     0     0           0     1     0     0
# 1     0     1     0           0     1     0           0     0     1     0
# 2     0     0     1           0     0     1           0     0     0     1
# 3     0     0     0           1     0     0           1     0     0     0
```

Be aware that if we do not have one value (for example 'D' in columns 'F2'), there won't be the 'F2_D' column, but that can be fix quite easily if you do need the column.